# integrate Camel with Spring cloud data flow

Tags: apache-camel, spring-cloud-dataflow

wanted to integrate Spring Cloud Data Flow /cloud task to invoke an existing Camel route.  would like to monitor this camel Job, using Spring Cloud Data Flow. How can we integrate Spring Cloud Data Flow with an existing Camel route application.

Comment: Why don't you use good-old camel's ProducerTemplate to integrate camel to Spring cloud data flow manually?